# Load 2GB in memory using java

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, performance, java-8

I have a query that it return 2GB in rows. I need to high performance reducing the selects in db. How do I load large amount of data in memory using Java?

EDIT

1. Using a hashmap (JAVA 8) to load the datas  to use it then, is it a solution?
2. Using a stream (JAVA 8), does it support this Lage amount of datas?

I have 48GB to ram to use in this process in memory.
I"m using Cassandra 3.11.10, spark 3.0, Java 8.

Comment: If you need help writing a query that *reduces* the data, you need to tell us more.

Comment: What kind of db are you using? Ho to get and process data depends on the db type.

Comment: I'm using a NOSQL db with large data's amount to be manipulate. I'm using spark and the queries performance was excellent. The problem is that to get a data all the time I need in the BD the performance low. One option is to load the result of the main query and manipulate than in memory. Do you have any idea?

Comment: *"How do I load large amount of data in memory using Java?"* You find the Documentation for the [Spring Data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data) variant that matches your database type, then read and learn. Follow the tutorials, and then write some code to load your actual data. Which part of this, other than the part where *you* have to do the work, is troubling you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The question was closed, but It is troubling me is to know the Java object to support this amount of data. I'm thinking in usem a BD in memory: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database. Do you think is a good idea?

Comment: So you're going to copy a database to another database, reorganizing the data for faster access? That is known as [Data Warehousing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse). You should probably read up on the topic.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. Another communit Java suggest to use ehcache spring boot or redis. I think will work to me.

Answer (score 1):

A good example of the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

The fundamental problem is that you have all this data in memory. The best way to solve this problem is to try to limit the size of the result size you get from the database.

Comment: A friend of mine do it in Python. So I thought the Java could do the same. This is not a commercial application. I have 48GB ram to process this datas in memory. I only need to know if there is a way to do it in Java as the Python do.

Comment: It really depends. The JVM can deal with 48 GB of ram especially since this isn't a commercial application. But you really have given too little information.

Comment: I cannot give more information about, because of the contract project. Thanks for your effort.